# C - accessing dynamic array within a struct

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to create cluster with dynamic array objects.

Struct definitions are following:

```
struct obj_t {
    int id;
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct cluster_t {
    int size;
    int capacity;
    struct obj_t *obj;
};
```

Function for adding object to cluster is:

```
void append_cluster(struct cluster_t *c, struct obj_t obj)
{
    if(c->capacity < (c->size + 1))
    {
        c = resize_cluster(c, c->size + 1);
    }
    if(c == NULL)
        return;
    c->obj[c->size] = obj;    //at this point program crashes.
    c->size++;
}
```

EDIT: Here is resize_cluster() function:

```
struct cluster_t *resize_cluster(struct cluster_t *c, int new_cap)
{
    if (c->capacity >= new_cap)
        return c;

    size_t size = sizeof(struct obj_t) * new_cap;

    void *arr = realloc(c->obj, size);
    if (arr == NULL)
        return NULL;

    c->obj = (struct obj_t*)arr;
    c->capacity = new_cap;
    return c;
}
```

EDIT 2: Here is cluster initialization:

```
void init_cluster(struct cluster_t *c, int cap)
{
    c = malloc(sizeof(struct cluster_t));
    c->size = 0;
    c->capacity = cap;
    c->obj = (struct obj_t*)malloc(cap * sizeof(struct obj_t));
}
```

I can't figure out why program crashes when I try to add the object to the array in cluster. Is accessing array this way wrong? If so, how should I access it?

Comment: Can we see`resize_cluster()`?

Comment: How are you initializing your cluster_t?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: I have added cluster initialization and resizing functions to question.

Comment: You are passing `c` by value to `init_cluster()`. So whatever you are passing as an argument remains uninitialized. You could change to: `struct cluster_t * init_cluster(int cap) {....;return c;}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the call to `init_cluster()`. The `c` parameter is passed-by-value, so whatever you are sending remains unmodified:

```
struct cluster_t * c;
init_cluster(c, 1);
// c is uninitialized!
```

One fix would be to pass a pointer to an object:

```
struct cluster_t c;
init_cluster(&c, 1);
```

Then remove `c = malloc(sizeof(struct cluster_t));` from `init_cluster()`;

Or, you could create an `alloc_cluster` function:

```
struct cluster_t * alloc_cluster(int cap)
{
    c = malloc(sizeof(struct cluster_t));
    c->size = 0;
    c->capacity = cap;
    c->obj = malloc(cap * sizeof(struct obj_t));
    return c;
}
```

And call it like:

```
struct cluster_t *c = init_cluster(1);
```

Comment: Removing `c = malloc(sizeof(struct cluster_t));` from `init_cluster()` works as I wanted. Thanks a lot.